# parsing SOAP xml with namespaces

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, soap

I have been trying to parse some info and followed the wonderful advise from http://lakenine.com/reading-xml-with-namespaces-using-linq/ I'm sure this is close, but I'm not getting any results to display. No errors, just no results. Breakpoints and checking variables shows that docx has the proper info, but my for loop gets skipped right over. I have played with multiple variations and only manage to crash the code. I believe the issue is with the XPathSelectElements parameter, but dont know what else to try. 
At this stage all I need is the token, but I will need to reuse the code later for returns that may have multiple results. Please advise and thank you in advance:

```
        string sampleXML = String.Concat(
                "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"",
                " xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"",
                " xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">",
                " <soap12:Body>",
                " <BeginSessionV2Response xmlns=\"http://ws.jobboard.com/jobs/\">",
                " <BeginSessionV2Result>ca5522fb93ef499f8ed010a5f4153af7-446298346-SB-4</BeginSessionV2Result>",
                " </BeginSessionV2Response>",
                " </soap12:Body>",
                " </soap12:Envelope>"
                );

                XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(sampleXML));
                System.Xml.XmlNameTable nameTable = reader.NameTable;
                System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = new System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(nameTable);

                namespaceManager.AddNamespace("soap12", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance/");
                XElement docx = XElement.Load(reader);

                string vbResultz = "start: ";
                var sessionKey = from pn
                in docx.XPathSelectElements("soap12:Body/BeginSessionV2Response/BeginSessionV2Result", namespaceManager)
                     select (string)pn;
                        foreach (string pn in sessionKey)
                        {
                             vbResultz += pn;
                        }

                        ViewBag.REsultz = vbResultz;           


        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `soap12` prefix you added have wrong uri. Add namespaces to namespaceManager this way :

```
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("soap12", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://ws.jobboard.com/jobs/");
```

Then you can use them in XPath expression like this :

```
......
docx.XPathSelectElements("soap12:Body/ns:BeginSessionV2Response/ns:BeginSessionV2Result", namespaceManager)
......
```

Notice that `<BeginSessionV2Response>` has default namespace (xmlns attribute without prefix), hence that element and it's descendant without prefix considered inside default namespace. Therefore, we need to add `ns` prefix in XPath query expression above.